# git repository with read only permissions

Tags: git

In git , how to clone a repositroy to another new repository with read only option is there any way to do it.are there any switches to do this

```
    git clone base-url new-url-with read only access
```

I do not want to do it with chmod command

Comment: i wanted to know about the switches.because i am aware that it can be done using chmod command

Comment: I think that git just decided not to reinvent the wheel. You can make a read-only repository by setting the filesystem permissions correctly, so instead of making their own version to make a read only repository, they just made sure that using permissions would work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chmod` command is your friend, as is the `umask` command.

Git itself **does not have any access control**, because the operating system and/or access protocol already has one, so it would be redundant. In fact, **access to git repository may not involve git** (it can even be pulled or even pushed with rsync), so git can't control access.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a checkout switch, but you could prevent it using a `git` way by setting up a [pre-commit hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html).

However, the hook could be bypassed with the `--no-verify` option, so that way is not as safe as using `chmod` to set the permissions.

Setting up the hook is quite easy:

1. create a file called `pre-commit` under `.git/hooks` in your repo that should be read only
2. the content of the file is trivial:
   `#!/bin/bash`
   `exit 1`
3. If a commit is being started now, the hook is invoked. The script always returns 1 and the commit is aborted. Excerpt from the [git book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html):

   > Exiting with non-zero status from this script causes the 'git-commit' to abort.

Simple and easy. Although it could be bypassed, it should be enough to prevent from accidential commits.

If you really need a safer version, go for `chmod` as [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159710/520162) by [Jan Hudec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201725/jan-hudec).